# First-order mutual-recursive functions Turing-complete or incomplete?

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages

Assume we have a C-like programming language with no pointer/heap semantics (i.e. there is no concept of memory; everything is on the stack). The only datatype supported is Integer, but suppose the Integer is infinitely large (i.e. without 32-bit, 64-bit, or any size limit).

Is it true that this language is Turing-*in*complete, but becomes complete if we add pointer/heap semantics (i.e. access to RAM-like memory)?

Comment: If we have arrays, linked lists, bigintegers or anything else to have an arbitrary large memory where you can potentially access any element, then it's Turing-complete (since you can just emulate any deterministic Turing machine with a single while-loop). Otherwise, it's not: the only way to have an arbitrary large memory are recursive calls. But this way, we won't be able to use all this data: let $f$ be a recursive function, and let $f^{i}$ be its call at depth $i$. Then to get access to data at $f^j$ for $j < i$, you have to exit $f^i$. But it means that you'll lose all data for $j > i$.

Comment: @Dmitry But functions can always pass everything to deeper functions as parameters, right? And conversely, deeper functions could encode its environment as an integer and pass that back to shallower functions; the latter could decode and use all the data.

Comment: @apen, if you code everything as an integer, it means that you use bigintegers (arbitrary large integers). As I and D.W. mentioned, it makes your language Turing-complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, as a heuristic, if your language includes primitives of unbounded size as well as standard control structures (e.g., loops and conditional statements), the language is likely to be Turing complete.  (Credits: I'm just expanding on [Dmitry's observation](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/129002/first-order-mutual-recursive-functions-turing-complete-or-incomplete/129036#comment270711_129002).)  I'll show a few examples below.

If your language doesn't have loops, you can simulate them with recursion.

## Linked lists

If your language includes linked lists, it will be Turing-complete.

In particular, you can encode a Turing machine with two linked lists.  You split the tape into two pieces, the part to the left of the head and the part to the right of the head.  Let $L$ be a linked list of the symbols on the tape to the left of the head, and $R$ the symbols to the right.  The linked list should start with the symbols closest to the head and go outward.

Now you can simulate each of the individual operations of the Turing machine using a few lines in your programming language.  For instance, shifting the tape head to the right can be done by popping an item $x$ from the front of $L$, then pushing $x$ onto the front of $R$.  The finite-state control works on finite data and so can be expressed as a finite number of simple operations.  Now put an infinite loop around this, with each iteration of the loop simulating one step of the Turing machine, and you have built an interpreter for a Turing machine in your language.

## Bigints

If your language includes bigints (i.e., integers that can be of unbounded size) and basic operations on them (e.g., add, multiply, compare, divide), then it will be Turing-complete.

In particular, you can simulate linked lists of items over a fixed alphabet using bigints.  Suppose you want to encode a linked list of bits.  Then you can encode this as a bigint by treating the sequence of bits in the linked list as the binary representation of an integer (the least significant bit is the first bit in the linked list, and so on).  Basic operations on the linked list can then be translated into operations on the integer.  For instance, popping a bit from the head of a linked list can be expressed as $b := L \bmod 2, L := (L-b)/2$; pushing a bit can be expressed as $L := 2L+b$; and so on.  More generally, if you have a linked list where each item is in the range $\{0,1,\dots,k-1\}$ (e.g., a tape alphabet of size $k$), then this can be viewed as an integer in base $k$.  There are some details -- for finite lists, you probably want to have one reserved symbol to indicate the end of the list -- but they don't change the general picture.

Now you can use this to simulate linked lists, and then use the construction above to simulate a Turing machine.

Comment: So this implies the answer to this question to be NO. It is Turing-complete, but you need to create an extra layer of machinery to make it function in that sense.

Comment: @apen I'm not sure what the distinction you're drawing is. If you have arbitrary-size integer arithmetic and a way of writing conditional loops, then for any Turing machine you can write a program that performs an equivalent computation. This is the definition of Turing completeness. You can do it all with stack-allocated bigints and recursion (no malloc, no looping constructs) as long as you have conditionals and unbounded stack size.

Comment: @AaronRotenberg I understand the point. I was just trying to further comment on that although it can simulate the Turing machine and thus Turing complete, you will need to invent some scaffolding structures such as linked lists to actually be able to program in the language with sanity. Not trying to debate the technical result here.

Comment: @apen, I'm a bit puzzled by your remarks.  I write an answer that says "yes" and you say you are interpreting my answer as implying "no".  I'm not sure how to respond to that.  I wonder if you're familiar with the definition of Turing-completeness.  Whether you label my method as inventing scaffolding or not is irrelevant to the question of Turing-completeness.  I wonder if maybe you were really curious about a different question (e.g., are linked lists necessary to be able to program with sanity?), but you asked something different (is this language Turing-complete?)?